# Linux Kernel Module that can list files and folders inside a given path

Tags: linux, file, linux-kernel, filesystems, linux-device-driver

I would like to know if it is possible to list files and folders inside a given folder from within the Linux Kernel. I bet there is a way.

I have searched on-line and gave it few shots, but still could not do it.

Thank you!

Comment: And how do you want to see the result? In `printk()`-d form in the kernel log is it okay?

Comment: BTW, there are a lot of such kernel modules, for example `ext4.ko`. You can communicate with them, for example, by the `ls` command. :-)

Comment: @peterh thank you for the comment. My intention is eventually open the file and read it. But for now, I am okay with a printing the path to kernel log with a printk(). Also, I want something generic that works with all ext* filesystems.

Comment: Your question is about directory read and not about file read. They are going by different syscalls even from userspace, an totally other from the kernel API.

Answer (score 0):

Reacting your comment: your question isn't about file reading, but getting the entries of a directory. About your last sentence: yes, every filesystem implements the `readdir()` function, so it would be filesystem-independent.

In my opinion, you need the following steps:

1. Research, how to write kernel modules. Tthere are very many tutorials on the net, including step-by-step tutorials with well commented examples.
2. Write a simple module, which `printk()`-s some simple text in its initialization function.
3. Research, how can you call system calls from a kernel module. It is probably not so simple, as from user space, but nearly surely possible.
4. The simplest way to pass through the path to the directory in a module parameter. Linux kernel modules can have multiple parameters, whose processing is very well automatized (essentially, you can directly bind the parameter name to static variables in the module).
5. After your module can call system calls, and has its input, you can now open this directory in its init function with the `opendir()` call. Then read its content (see `readdir()`), and finally output the result with `printk()`.

Probably there will be some obstacles, for example maybe you can't use syscalls from the module init function, or similar, but none of them will be really hard.